# Codeigniter escape - unescape data from database

Tags: database, codeigniter, quotes

Please do not think to go for negative the question via reading the question.
because I have searched a lot and I know that everywhere this question has been asked a lot But I don't know I am not getting proper solution of this.

I want the data to be safe (from sql injection and xss ) in storing in DB and retrieving from DB.

my CI config settings :

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

My DB Add Query :

```
$add_data['name'] = $this->db->escape($name);
.....
.....
$this->db->insert($this->table, $add_data);
```

My DB View Query :

```
$q =$this->db->select($this->fld);
$q = $this->db->where("$this->cond");
$q = $this->db->order_by($this->sortid, $this->sortby);
$q = $this->db->limit( $this->limit,$this->offset);
$ret=$q->get()->result_array();
```

**My Problem is:**

> DB Value is having single quotes : For ex.  if $name = abc in DB it is
>   : 'abc'

**Question :**

> If I want to display the quoted data How can I display them without quotes.

**Plus**

> How can I prevent adding the single quotes in database.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to escape data when using `CI insert`. Active records escapes values automatic for you. In your example:

```
/* $add_data['name'] = $this->db->escape($name); - not need */
$add_data['name'] = $name;
.....
.....
$this->db->insert($this->table, $add_data);
```

Read **[CI Active Records](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)**. There are explanation of every function.Also which one need escape , which not

Comment: But if I do not add $this->db->escape then It is not adding slashes. when actually it is needed.
e.x.
$add_data['name'] = Marry X'Mas

Answer (score 0):

Active records escapes values automatically. And for displaying strings without quotes, u can use string helper.

```
$string="Joe's \"dinner\"";
$string=strip_quotes($string); //results in "Joes dinner"
```

Its in the [User's Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html).

Comment: and dont forget to load the string helper:
`$this->load->helper('string');`

Comment: Not Working...
Ex.
My Value is : AA'BB"CC\DD/EE`FF;GG~HH

in Add db->escape is used.
in DB it is showing : 'AA\'BB\"CC\\DD/EE`FF;GG~HH'

in display : strip_quotes is used.
in Display it is : 'AA'BB"CC\DD/EE`FF;GG~HH'